# How can I downgrade gcc 4.6.3 to 4.4.3?

Tags: gcc, gnu

I have gcc-4.6.3 installed in my PC.but for my project I need gcc-4.4.3 version.
I do not mind removing gcc-4.6.3 but I badly need gcc-4.4.3.
How can I downgrade?
or how can I keep two gcc and make gcc-4.4.3 as primary GCC.?

Comment: What is your distribution/OS?

Comment: Is it really impossible to port the code forward? It shouldn't be _too_ hard, and you reap the benefits of lots of impovements in GCC (and the languages).

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the  [general guide to install multiple versions of GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple).

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` or `yum` should simplify a lot for you. You can even compile your own and use that path and it will pick the gcc of the path you specified.

Comment: The package repositories won't carry museum-worthy versions of GCC around (except possibly for oldish, "enterprise" distributions, but those will soon be end-of-life too).

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu, (and others maybe), you can have both, go to synaptic package manager then choose the version you want to use, install it, the in terminal enter : "gcc" without the (") the press tab twice or more the terminal then will show you all gcc versions, type the one you want (always)
e.g. 
gcc-4.2 -o  yourfile.c